# Test presence of ActiveRecord callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec3

How can you test the presence of a callback in your model, specifically one that's triggered by creating a record, such as `after_create` or `after_commit on: :create`?

Here's an example callback with the (empty) method that it calls.

```
# app/models/inbound_email.rb

class InboundEmail < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :notify_if_spam, on: :create

  def notify_if_spam; end
end
```

Here's the pending spec, using RSpec 3.

```
# spec/models/inbound_email_spec.rb

describe InboundEmail do
  describe "#notify_if_spam" do
    it "is called after new record is created"
  end
end
```

Using a [message expectation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-1/docs/basics/expecting-messages) to test that the method is called seems like the way to go.
For example:

```
expect(FactoryGirl.create(:inbound_email)).to receive(:notify_if_spam)
```

But that doesn't work. Another way is to test that when a record is created, something inside the called method happens (e.g. email sent, message logged). That implies that the method did get called and therefore the callback is present. However, I find that a sloppy solution since you're really testing something else (e.g. email sent, message logged) so I'm not looking for solutions like that.

Comment: Why don't you like message expectations?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom I'm not sure why you think I dislike message expectations? I think the solution will likely involve a message expectation, as mentioned in my example.

Comment: This question is unclear. Do you want to test whether the method exists? Or whether the callback is called?

Comment: @Substantial I want to test that the callback is present and calls the correct method. Testing whether the method `notify_if_spam` is called when a record is created seems to me like the most obvious way to do that.

Comment: That is the confusing part. What exactly do you mean by "the callback is present"?

Comment: @Substantial that the line of code `after_commit :notify_if_spam, on: :create` is in the model.

Comment: @Dennis I'm confused because you seem to have a solution for your problem. So I'm unclear as to what it is you're asking.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom The sample solution I provide doesn't work unfortunately. I'll edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: does it work if you build the object (don't save it), set your expectation & then save it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Frederick Cheung is right.  This should work.  The problem with your example is that the callback has already been called *before* the expectation has been set.

```
describe InboundEmail do
  describe "#notify_if_spam" do
    it "is called after new record is created" do
      ie = FactoryGirl.build(:inbound_email)
      expect(ie).to receive(:notify_if_spam)
      ie.save!
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That's it! Just had to replace `create` with `save` in your example. Thanks.